# Pandas dynamic date time week start

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, boolean, python-datetime

I am trying to create a dynamic date time function in my pandas dataframe to recognize the value in the 'Date' column and let me know the respective week start in the 'Week' column.

- Starting week date is always a Monday, except if the week spills into another month
- If it does spill into another month, the week end date will be the last day of the week start month
- The first of the new month will represent the week start for the dates that spilled over, week end will still be Sunday

I'm having difficulty incorporating the function I created below into the Pandas dataframe:

```
    def week(rawdate):
        dt = datetime.strptime(rawdate, '%m/%d/%Y')
        currentweekstart = dt - timedelta(days = dt.weekday())
        currentweekstart2 = currentweekstart.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        currentweekmonth = currentweekstart.strftime('%m')
        currentweekfinish = currentweekstart + timedelta(days = 6)
        currentweekfinish2 = currentweekfinish.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        currentweekfinishmonth = currentweekfinish.strftime('%m')

        if dt.strftime('%m') == currentweekmonth:
            currentweekstart2 
            return currentweekstart2

        else: #start date is the 1st date of new month week
            nextweekstart = datetime.strptime(currentweekfinish.strftime('%m/1/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
            nextweekstart2 = nextweekstart.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
            return nextweekstart2
```

Any help would be appreciated!

edit: Updated function with the revised variables

Comment: How does your dataframe look like?

Comment: Also, seems like there are some issues in your function , where is `weekstart` defined ? (which is returned in the else part) , also in the `if` part you are doing - `currentweekstart2` - which is no-op

Comment: I updated the else return to nextweekstart2. The function works overall, I am struggling with integrating it into the Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your logic for function `week(rawdate)` is correct, You can use the [`series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) function to apply a function to all values in a series (a pandas column) , and this returns a new series , which you can assign to your new pandas column.

Example -

```
df['Week'] = df['Date'].apply(week)
```

Some issues I can see in the function -

1. `weekstart` is not defined (which is returned in the else part) .
2. Also in the `if` part you are doing - `currentweekstart2` - which is no-op

Comment: To keep the dataframe simple, there is a column for 'Date' and column for 'Week'. There are date values in 'Date' and I need to run the function to reference the date to determine the start week.

Could you elaborate on the issue with the "if" portion of the function? What can I do to improve it?

Comment: There is no issue , its just that you do - `currentweekstart2 ` - which is no operation

Comment: anyway try the `apply` function i specified above.

Comment: Just tried applying the function and it looks like I'm receiving a couple of errors.

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:56983)()



AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: maybe the function does not expect the values from `Date` column, are you sure it expects that?

Comment: I just ran df.dtypes to look at the data type of the 'Date' column and it is an object so it should work.

Comment: ---> 19 wuadmobdf['Week'] = wuadmobdf['Date'].apply(week)

          -> 2058         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

          pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:56983)()

          AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: import your datetime as - `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: You are awesome! That did the trick, I had originally only had date and timedelta imported.